# Average value of area of circles

Tags: calculus

I am supposed to find the average value of the area of circles whose radii vary from $0$ to $R$.

I know that the formula for the arithmetic mean of a function $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ is
$$\frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

So for these circles it seems like it would now be this:
$$\begin{align}
\mu &= \frac{1}{R} \int_0^R \pi r^2\,dr \\
&=\frac{\pi}{R} \left(\frac {R^3}{3}\right) \\
&=\frac{R^3 \pi}{3}
\end{align}$$

So I try and verify this using three circles that are easy to calculate, of radius $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Using $$\frac{ \pi + 4 \pi + 9 \pi}{3}$$
gives me $\frac{14\pi}{3}$

Using my formula gives me $9 \pi$.

This makes me reevaluate what I am doing; it seems like my previously discovered formula accounts for a circle of radius $0$. I compensate for that Using $$\frac{ \pi + 4 \pi + 9 \pi}{4} = \frac{7\pi}{2}$$

Still wrong, what did I do incorrectly?

Comment: You forgot to cancel one $R$ from your integral. It should read $\pi R^2/3$. Remember the following "reality check". You measure $R$ in feet or meters, whichever is standard from where you are. Therefore $R^3$ has units that are cubic feet or cubic meters. Now how on earth could the average **area** be some number of cubic ft or meters?

Comment: Your formula accounts for all the $R\in\mathbb{R^+}$ while you assumed $R\in\mathbb{N}$ in your verification.

Comment: You are misunderstanding a fundamental difference between discrete and continuous averages. When you check your work with three distinct radii, you are not considering the continuum between them.

Comment: ... and what other have said about discrete vs. continuous variables. There is a branch of numerical analysis that deals with questions such as how to select a finite set of sample points in such a way that the weighted average calculated at those points equals the continuous average. None of your suggestions fit.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Do you have any references on that? I am interested.

Comment: @Orangutango: What I had in mind are formulas that are designed to be accurate up to certain degree of polynomial factor in the integrand. See [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature) for starters. If the domain is the surface of an $n$-sphere, then [spherical designs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_design) do the same thing. IANA, so there's probably a lot more. Those are the bits that have crossed my path.

Comment: Note that $\frac{7\pi}{2}$ is a fairly good approximation to the (corrected) continuous average of $3\pi$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen The extra R came from when I evaluated it as a definite integral.

Comment: I can evaluate the definite integral, thank you. But you were supposed to multiply the definite integral by $1/R$. See my first comment for a way of quickly seeing that something went wrong. That is one of the things I teach my calculus students to check when critically appraising the answer they got.

Comment: I don't know if that really helps, cubic feet makes as much sense as feet^5

Answer (score 4):

As expalined in the comments, you have an extra $R$, so that the formula should read:
$$R^2\pi \over 3$$
I'd like to relate this to the discrete calculation you did. For $n$ circles of radius $1,2..n$, the average area is:
$${\pi \over n} \sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = {\pi\over6} (n+1) (2 n+1)= {\pi n^2\over 3} + O(n)$$
Thus, you see that as  the number of concentric circles becomes larger, approximating the integral by discrete concentric circles becomes closer to your integral formula.

Comment: The extra R came from when I evaluated it like a definite integral.